# Change ServiceProvider for Active Multipageeditor Page

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jface

I work on a `MultiPageEditor` in Eclipse. The Editor has a variable number of pages.
Each of the Pages displays a `JTree`. I have made my own `Jtree` witch implements the `ISelectionProvider`. When I select a leaf its display Information about the leaf 
to the Propertys view.

The Editor Pages where generate by a loop, all JTrees where Saved in an ArrayList. 
When I add a ServiceProvider like this:

```
getSite().setSelectionProvider(trees.get(0));
```

it works. But when I change the ServiceProvider when changing the page:

```
@Override
protected void pageChange(int newPageIndex) {
    if (newPageIndex != 0)
    {
        getSite().setSelectionProvider(trees.get(newPageIndex-1));
    }
}
```

nothing works.

How can I change the `SelectionProvider` dynamically based on the active EditorPage?

Comment: You don't call super.pageChange

Comment: Yeah i forgot, but it still does not work with super

Comment: What do you mean with it does not work? Do you expect that your Properties view is refreshed when changing the page or changing the page **and** selecting an item from the tree on the new page? There won't be fired any event just if you set a new selection provider (see `org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorSite.setSelectionProvider(ISelectionProvider)`?.

Comment: Sorry, but i dont get it